# Do an action on every customers in db Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the group_id of all customers in my database.
So I tried to do this:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$customerSubscriptionHelper = Mage::helper('mymodule_customer/subscription');

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $isCustomerSubscribed = $customerSubscriptionHelper->getCustomerActiveSubscription($customer);
    if (!$isCustomerSubscribed) {
        $customer->setData('group_id', '1');
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

But I don't know if it's a good way to 'parse' a database like this...
Thanks !

Comment: can a moderator move this post on magento exchange ? sorry :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on when (on what conditions) and how frequent are you doing the activity.

Lets say if you are doing this process as soon as the user visits the cart page or visits the homepage , then this would be a bad approach to continue with.

As this approach would work well with small data but would result in performance issue when the volume of data grows, as you will be looping through a lots of data frequently.

A better way would be to apply an observer and update the info of the current user at a time.

Again i don't know what exactly is your use case and why are you updating all the users at once, and on what conditions are you updating.

But this would run into performance issue with large volume of data.But if your data is not huge than you can probably use this.

Thanks